# Why VirtualPC reset clock to host clock?

Tags: microsoft-virtual-pc

I tried to change the hour of my windows inside Virtual PC but each time it comes back to the clock of the host. How to prevent this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is part of the way it works.

Stop the Virtual Machine and find the folder that contains your .vmc file (configuration file).

Open it up in notepad and within the `<Integration>` and `<Microsoft>` tags, add the following:

```
    <components>
        <host_time_sync>
            <enabled type="boolean">false</enabled>
        </host_time_sync>
    </components>
```

[In this guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2007/11/28/disabling-time-synchronization-under-virtual-pc-2007.aspx), it shows to do it straight after `</mouse>`

Comment: Great thanks, couldn't suspect I could configure this :)

Answer (score 0):

> You can stop the clock synchronization between host machine and guest machine by following these steps
>
> 1. Open Virtual PC and start your guest Operating System
>      After it fully loads
> 2. Click on Start and than Click on Run and type `services.msc`
>      A window will pop-up listed all avalable services
> 3. Now here we have to find service
>      Virtual Machine Additions Services Application
> 4. Right Click on the service and click on Stop
>
>    Note: You can also click on properties and set the startup type to Disabled, this way it will never starts at it's own, though you can manually start it later.
> 5. Close window
>
> Now you can change the time in guest OS and this time it will not try to sync with the Host machine

[Source](http://techgulf.blogspot.com/2012/08/stop-clock-sync-with-host-machine-in.html)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.